# Google Fit Rest API - cant see any useful data

Tags: google-fit

Hi just wondering how I get real data back from the following. I put in this into Oauth 2.0 playgournd:

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derive_step_cadence<-raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:LGE:Nexus 5:bc5f1b97:Step Counter/datasets/8587796212108459505-8587784116108409439

And I get back this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 202
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-location: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derive_step_cadence<-raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:LGE:Nexus 5:bc5f1b97:Step Counter/datasets/8587796212108459505-8587784116108409439
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Etag: "hLUJCvL5ZSSqXM3VrwyiV-fn_Cc/UTWu-5kuRnTemL1Tzb1qSZ4O9uk"
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 04:22:06 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "8587784116108409439", 
  "maxEndTimeNs": "8587796212108459505", 
  "dataSourceId": "derive_step_cadence<-raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:LGE:Nexus 5:bc5f1b97:Step Counter
}

Not any useful data.

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks
Russ

Comment: Did you find any solution for this case? I have the same situation now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that timestamp that you provide at the end of the endpoint is in **nanotime** format.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derive_step_cadence<-raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:LGE:Nexus 5:bc5f1b97:Step Counter/datasets/000000-1720845034000000000
```

This solution works like a charm